camel migration 3.x to 4.x bean creation issue with defaultOperationName
In camel 3.x we are able to use the same bean defenition with changing defaultOperationName passing to it. But now after upgrade to camel 4.x. each operation is asked to create different bean as per error. This is by design?
Failed to resolve end point 
due to : Different URI refer to the same CxfEndpoint Bean instance with ID :  but with different parameters.
Why cxf end point not working as expected.
